# Custom NSURLProtocol added to configuration.protocolClasses prevents working of default url protocols

Tags: ios, nsurlprotocol

I try to add a custom `NSURLProtocol` to a `NSURLSession` in order to serve test data for some calls, while providing the normal internet connectivity for all other calls. I need to do this by adding the `NSURLProtocol` to the session configuration's `protocolClasses`, as the session resides in a library that is included in the project.

For some reason my setup does deliver the test data right when my custom protocol takes the request by returning `true` for the `canInitWithRequest` call, but for all other requests (when it returns `false`) the default protocols that are still in the `protocolClasses` behind my custom protocol get the request and even return `true` on the `canInitWithRequest` call, **but they never send the request to the internet** and deliver a request timeout after 30 seconds instead. When I remove my custom protocol from the `protocolClasses`, everything works fine - just my test data is not served anymore, of course.

This is the code I use for installing the protocol:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    NSMutableArray* protocols = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses];
    [protocols insertObject:[MyProtocol class] atIndex:0];
    sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses = protocols;
    mySession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
```

When I register the custom protocol with `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyProtocol class]]`, the fallthrough does work, but as written I can't use this approach in my project.

Any idea on why this is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a misprint in your code snippet, it should be `protocols` instead of `array` variable. ))

I think that in case of custom protocol, it makes sense to see protocol client and so on( `propertyFoKey: inRequest:`)
Is the method `startLoading`(or `stopLoading`) is  called?

Ah, I have re read your question.

In case  of `[NSURLProtocol registerClass]` , the custom class, if being the latest registered, will handle URL scheme.
In your case it seems that there is another(void) protocol that handles the request.

Comment: Thanks for the misspelling tip, corrected. I stepped into the debugger and found that the internal class _NSURLHTTPProtocol is called for falling through http requests, and it even returns true for the canInitWithRequest call, - it's just not doing anything anymore after that ...

Comment: add your protocol as a last element into the array, rebuild app, should help))

Comment: then the default http protocol catches the request first and my specific protocol does not get the chance to catch eg "http://testdata.com" and return the test data, as the http protocol will try to handle the http address ...